# How can I ask from Ant Media Server the number of current viewers

Tags: linux, bash, ant-media-server-sdk

I tried in this way:

```
netstat -a | grep EST|grep -v localhost| grep \:5080| cut -d' ' -f 16-17|cut -d':' -f1|sort|uniq|wc -l
```

But it obviously can't show viewers from same ip.
Surely there is a better way to do this...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want to access your total viewers count?

You can reach the viewer numbers with the REST Service. Could you please check this https://antmedia.io/rest/#/BroadcastRestService/getBroadcastStatistics

Comment: Yes, thank you!
This is the url what wanted
http://localhost:5080/LiveApp/rest/v2/broadcasts/list/0/10
And the hlsViewerCount variable was what I needed.